# Group dates based on timestamps

Tags: javascript, datetime, grouping

I have an array of timestamps for when an application was used in the following format, for example: `July 8, 2020 at 10:10:48 AM UTC+2`, I need to write code that groups each timestamp based on the number of days ago the application was used (1 day, 5 days, 7 days, 10 days or more) and count how many devices there were based on the groups. I am struggling to get that working. So far I have the code to calculate amount of days between 2 dates, but I am unsure of how I can group and count.

```
function daysDifference(date1, date2) 
 {

  var difference=(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / 1000;
  difference/= (60 * 60 * 24);
  return Math.abs(Math.round(difference));
  
 }
```

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may

- traverse your source array of date strings with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) parsing each item with [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) constructor and calculating the difference between resulting date and current date
- having delta in days (not necessarily integer) you may use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the least interval resulting delta falls in or assign `'more'` as a key if no match is found
- build up the resulting object where respective `key` is incremented for each source array item:

```js
const src = Array.from(
        {length: 10},
        () => new Date(Date.now()-15*864e5+Math.random()*15*864e5).toString()),           
          // above is just mocking the source data - array filled with 
          // date  strings (random dates up to 15 days from now)
          
      result = src.reduce((r,dateStr) => {
        const today = new Date(),
              date = new Date(dateStr),
              deltaDays = (today-date)/864e5,
              key = [1,3,5,7].find(n => deltaDays <= n)||'more'
        r[key] = (r[key]||0)+1
        return r
      }, {})
      
console.log('Source data: ', JSON.stringify(src))
console.log('Result :', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you so much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to return the count (not groupings):

```js
const dates = [
  new Date('July 12, 2020 00:15:30'),
  new Date('July 12, 2020 03:15:30'),
  new Date('July 07, 2020 02:15:30'),
  new Date('July 02, 2020 01:15:30'),
  new Date('July 08, 2020 12:15:30'),
  new Date('July 07, 2020 00:15:30'),
  new Date('July 07, 2020 03:15:30'),
  new Date('July 01, 2020 00:15:30')
]

const today = new Date();


function daysDifference(date1, date2) {
  var difference = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / 1000;
  difference /= (60 * 60 * 24);
  return Math.abs(Math.round(difference))

}


function countDifferences(arr, constant) {
  return arr.reduce((output, date) => {
    let key = daysDifference(date, constant);
    output[key] ? output[key] += 1 : output[key] = 1;
    return output
  }, {})
}

console.log(countDifferences(dates,today))
```